# В Select поле подгружается не весь список

Tags: javascript, php, html, php7, html-select

При выборе определенной категории в первом поле, должны подгружаться во второе поле принадлежащие к этой категории записи. Они подгружаются, но почему-то только 33 записи, остальные нет. Кто знает в чем проблема? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="menu-select" style="d-flex;">

          <select name="" id="children" style="margin-right: 15px;">
              <option value="">Выберите вид спорта:</option>
            <? foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
                <option value="<?=$term->term_id?>"><?=$term->name?></option>
              <? } ?>
          </select>

          <select name="" id="posts"></select>
</div>

<script>
      $(function () {
          $('#posts').change(function () {
              var hr = $(this).val();
              location.href = hr;
          });
         $('#children').change(function () {
             let par = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '/posts.php?parent='+par,
                success: function (res) {
                    $('#posts').html(res);
                }
            })
         });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Скиньте код как вы подгружаете во второй select

Comment: @Ravshan Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Добавьте не AJAX код, а PHP код в файле get.php, который делает запрос к базе данных

Comment: Может у вас стоит `limit`? Или какое-то условие, из-за которого не все данные приходят

Comment: @Евгений, а где искать это условие, вроде весь код скинул

Comment: В php коде, покажи php код, где ты делаешь запрос к бд, выше уже просили

Answer (score 0):

В названии тридцать четвертой записи есть специальные символы, которые портят html.

Comment: нет, никаких отличных символов нет

Comment: @ChikChirik Я Вам просто должен поверить?

Comment: Да, у 34 записи все по аналогии с предыдущими. Суть в том, что в главной категории изначально выводились ниже списком записи, и вот у них также не выводилось все, это мне исправили, а в меню остался косяк, вот теперь разбираюсь...

Comment: @ChikChirik Я не понимаю, о чем Вы говорите. Я Вам уже объяснил в чем дело.

Comment: В названии 34 записи нет никаких специальных символов.

Comment: @ChikChirik А я говорю - есть.